# I haven’t liked it lately or I haven’t been liking it lately. Which is better to use?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

> I haven’t liked it lately

> I haven’t been liking it lately.

Which one is better?

I do feel like the latter is more of a conversational form, isn’t it?

And obviously “like” is a non-continuous verb.

But what about these examples?

> “I haven’t liked her cooking lately.” - doesn’t sound quite right.
>
> “I haven’t been liking her cooking lately.” - this one sounds way
> better to me.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

> I haven’t liked it lately

This suggests that the problem might be with "it" (eg the cooking).

> I haven’t been liking it lately.

This suggests that the problem might be with you (eg, your tastes have changed, you have been off your food).

---

For example, a person might go to the doctor and say "I haven't been tasting my food lately" to mean that they think something is wrong with their sense of taste. They wouldn't say to the doctor "I haven't tasted food recently", because that sounds like no food has passed their lips!